# PreProcessor: store array of strings at compile-time

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I need a container of strings at compile-time, which should be iterable at runtime.
However, I really need a macro, so that some functions will be produced (can't think of a way to do that with templated code at namespace-level).

But in the following code I get 'error: 'sequence' in 'class LaLaLa' does not name a type', which happens within the ASSIGN macro (I think).
Can somebody help me with this?

```
#define CREATE_FUNCTION(r, data, i, elem) // creates a function with name 'do_something_with_##elem()'

#define ASSIGN(r, data, i, elem) data::sequence[i] = elem;

#define TO_ARRAY(name, _seq)                                          \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(CREATE_FUNCTION, _, _seq)                   \
    class name                                                        \
    {                                                                 \
    public:                                                           \
        static constexpr std::size_t size = BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(_seq);  \
        static std::string sequence[size];                            \
    };                                                                \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(ASSIGN, name, _seq)


TO_ARRAY(LaLaLa, (x)(y)(z)(a))
```

Then I would like to use it something like this:

```
do_something_with_x();
do_something_with_z();
std::vector<std::string> use_strings;
for(size_t i = 0; i < LaLaLa::size; ++i)
{
   use_strings.push_back(LaLaLa::sequence[i]);
}
// use_strings == {"x", "y", "z", "a"}
```

Comment: Well, have you had a look at what your code looks like after the preprocessor has done the substitutions?

Comment: ohh no, didn't think of that - how do I do that?

Comment: `g++ -E file.cpp` if you use gcc.

Comment: hmm, I need to include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>, but `g++ -E -B /path-to/boost-1.48.0/` file.cpp doesn't resolve that

Comment: Uh. Do you have the necessary `#include` statements in your source file? You don't need the `-B ...`, if boost is in `/usr/include/boost` then `#include<boost/.../...>`  will find the files.

Comment: I just sym-linked it to /usr/include/boost, but the included file <boost/preprocessor.hpp> is still not found

Comment: That's because there is no <boost/preprocessor.hpp>. Please read the documentation of the boost functions you are using to see which headers you need to include.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/headers/preprocessor.html

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, I may have been too quick with my earlier comment. Your symlink is probably wrong then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't the preprocessor - using the sequence directly after the class definition is the problem. (needs to be done within a function or something like that)